# Is a real user account required for Admin SDK impersonation?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

In my application I am listing all the users in a Google Apps domain. I have a Service Account that I use to authenticate my application. So far so good.

Before listing the users, I need to provide a user account that my application can impersonate, like this:

```
new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(asList(scopes))
            .setServiceAccountUser(usernameToImpersonate)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(privateKey)
            .build();
```

That works fine, but I have two issues:

- I currently don't store the admin account username, so I need to jump through some hoops to get that in, and in some cases I will have to ask my customers.
- The account given as an admin account (having access to the Admin SDK) might not have admin rights forever. If the customer decides that someone else should be admin, my application won't work anymore.

Is there a way around this? I have permissions to impersonate any user in the domain, which means I can just pick one of the admins, but the problem is that I don't know who's the admin until I have made this request. Catch 22.

I thought I could just use the Service Account Email instead of a real user email (which would be the ideal solution), but that just gives me weird NullPointerExceptions from the Google API.

EDIT sept 25, 2014:

Since a few days ago, Google now allows any user to list users in a domain (also including subdomains).

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.se/2014/09/new-features-in-admin-sdk-custom-user.html

However, this has two limitations which mean that this is not something I can benefit from for my particular use case.

1. You still need a (active) username to make a request, and how are you going to get that username if you can't list the users? I might have a username from the signup, but that account may be deleted at any time. Still catch 22.
2. If you are using a non-admin account, you are forced to set viewType to "domain_public", which means you will only be able to see a subset of the available fields. The "suspended" field is not one of them, and you also won't get any suspended users in the response.
   (documentation available here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list)

I could live with the "suspended" limitation, but since I can't get a list of users without already having a user, this is not helping me.